# Subsection of an Array in JS/JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

I'm looking to extract a subsection of a javascript array of objects based on a certain condition, e.g:

```
object.property == 2
```

I know that I could look through and build a new array from the ones that match, but I was wondering whether there was a shorthand for this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [grep()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.grep/).

```
var arr = [ 1, 2, 3 ];
var subset = $.grep(arr,function(n,i){ return n >= 2 });
// subset = [2, 3]
```

Answer (score 2):

Use http://api.jquery.com/filter/

e.g.

```
$(yourCollection).filter(function(){
    return (this.property == 2);
});
```

EDIT:
jsFiddle with both approaches benchmarked: http://jsfiddle.net/StuperUser/6AfQj/

Comment: You can wrap arrays e.g. `$(array)`